# Search field in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I have an index page with users list where I want to implement a search field, and filtering records based on the text field of users

```
scope :filter_users ->(params[:search]) { where("name like %#{params[:search]}%)
```

where i also need to check the the associated object name. I.e user belongs to organization, I need to add condition at scope to check the organisation name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question was missing this, but I'll suppose your model is something like:

```
class User
  belongs_to :organization
end

class Organization
  has_many :users
end
```

To setup a search on the relation, you'll first need to join to the organization table onto `users` and search on the result of the join, filtering both on the user name and the organization name. It would look something like:

```
class User
  belongs_to :organization

  # I took the liberty of fixing your simple search syntax
  scope :simple_search,  ->(query) { where('name like ?', "%#{query}%") }
  # The complex search:
  # 1. Inner joins users table to organizations table
  # 2. Applies a where conditions to the result of the join (note: we need to
  # specify the table name in the where because both models have a name field)
  scope :complex_search, ->(query) { joins(:organization).where('users.name LIKE :q OR organizations.name LIKE :q', query:"%#{query}%")}
end
```

And used like this:

```
# returns only users whose name matches '%ben%'
User.simple_search('ben')  
# returns users whose name matches '%ben%' and users belonging to
# companies whose name matches '%ben%'
User.complex_search('ben')
```

You can find an example of this (and interesting details about things I used in my answer, and lots of other things as well) in the official [Active Record Query Interface guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html), and for this particular matter, in the [specifying conditions on the joined tables](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables) section.